# O que é mais eficiente, uma query complexa ou tratar os resultados?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu posso fazer isso:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '
                    . 'data_companies '
                    . 'INNER JOIN data_companies_extra_infos ON' 
                    . 'data_companies.cod = data_companies_extra_infos.relationship';
   $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
```

E ter o resultado que eu quero.

Ou, eu posso fazer isso:

```
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '
                . 'data_companies ';
  $data = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);


  $sql_ex = 'SELECT * FROM '
                . 'data_companies_extra_infos ';
  $rs_ex = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql_ex);
  $data = [];
  foreach($rs as $row){
      foreach($rs_ex as $row_ex){
           if($row['cod'] == $row_ex['relationship']){
               $data[] = array_merge($row,$row_ex);
           }
      }
  }
```

E tambem ter o resultado que eu quero.
Bom, esse é um exemplo simples, acredito que a primeira opção seja melhor, mas e em casos em que haverá uma query complexa envolvendo calculos, 4 ou 5 tabelas e varios filtros para clausula `WHERE`.

> Qual das duas é melhor em questão de desempenho ?

Em outras palavras:

> É melhor eu fazer um query gigante e complexa, ou fazer várias querys simples e tratar os resultados com o PHP ?

PS: A função select_by_query_string() executa a query, trata e codifica os resultados e depois devolve um array.

PS2: Pessoalmente acho a segunda opção mais fácil.

Comment: Normalmente, costuma-se jogar serviço de busca para o banco. Eu diria que você deveria testar, e testar, e testar, e testar....

Comment: Eu não tenho aval para uma resposta completa (pois, sou da POO mesmo). Entretanto, lembre-se que, o SGBD foi desenvolvido especificamente para trabalhar com dados. A questão de índices também afetaria, o SGBD pode usá-los para encontrar mais rapidamente o(s) registro(s) solicitado(s). Além disso, se você for trazer uma quantidade enorme de dados para tratar na aplicação, você terá um tempo gasto com a transição dos dados do SGBD para a aplicação, além de um consumo exagerado de memória com algo que poderia ser realizado pelo SGBD.

Comment: Diria que é "relativo".

Comment: Você pode fazer um teste, colocando um cronômetro. Gostaria de elaborar uma resposta, mas não vai dar agora.

Comment: Um detalhe que ficou faltando, seu 2º exemplo simples é uma das soluções do problema N+1. Remove-se o JOIN e realiza duas consultas separadas para transicionar menos dados entre o SGBD e a aplicação. Mas no seu caso é sem filtros. Minha resposta acima continua a mesma quando for adicionados filtros.

Comment: @GabrielHeming é exatamente esse o 'Q' de eu preferir utilizar do segundo modo, evito fadiga no meu banco, e também porque meu servidor de processamento é consideravelmente mais potente que minha DB, e também, meu sistema processa em dois bancos separados a mesma ação, um com o estado atual (para operacional) e um somático com todo histórico de todos os valores que estiveram em todos os campos desde de sempre, acho que vou dar um reformulada na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que a resposta irá variar de acordo com o cenário.

Os *sgbd's* antes de efetuar uma consulta, tentam otimizar a mesma criando um plano de execução das consultas.

Vejo que está usando mysql. Uma forma de você testar a performance de suas consultas é utilizando a ferramenta de *explain* do `Mysql workbench`. Ela está disponível  no menu query ou pelo atalho <kbd>Ctlr</kbd> +
 <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Através desta funcionalidade você pode ver o plano de execução que o *sgbd* utilizou e o custo de cada etapa.

Assim você pode definir qual será a melhor forma de utilizar sua consulta, necessidade de criação de índices , etc.. de acordo com o cenário.

[image: Tela do explain]